# Work with Firestore in offline

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There are a  [sample of application with Firestore](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/quickstart-android/firestore/README.md) in documentation. I ran this app, and it works with the network.

If I turn off the Internet and open the application - the data about restaurants will loaded from the cache and I can see it. But if I try to comment any restaurant I will get an error and **the data won`t load to the cache.**

There are an information about [how to work with Firestore when you offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline). So, in MainActivity on line 109 I added this code:

```
mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
                .build();
mFirestore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

Then, I deleted the app and ran it again with the Internet, and then I turn off the Internet and tried to send a comment in offline. But the result is the same.

So, **what should I do if I want to load the data to the cache when the app is offline**?

Comment: Can you show the code that raises the error? Also: what's the error do you get?

Comment: Also note that [for Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence). So you don't need to set it yourself

Comment: are you using onCompleteListener when you are seting values for your comments ? i mean, if you comment , the listener will be waiting to complete the process and after that it will post it, with this you cant have any problem i think

Comment: as Frank said, the offline feature is always enabled, i think you are getting an error because you are trying to post a value into firebase with an asynctask maybe ? or not using the listener correctly

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, @IDroid, it seems to me that I incorrectly described the problem. It is a ready-made example which I took [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/samples-android). There is not any error in code when the device is offline. I mean, if I try to add the data in offline the OnFailureListener will work. It`s not an error, it is not a crash, it is just OnFailureListener working.

Comment: are your dependencies up to date ?

Comment: they were already registered in the build.gradle file. And app works correctly when device in online, so I think there is all right with dependencies.